# how to connect couchdb database using javascript

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am new to couchDB and Javascript.
I need a simple java script code for connecting CouchDB database and reading a document and displaying the content in the browser window.

Please anyone help me.

Thanks,
Nandha.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript in a browser? Or server side JS, like node.js?

Comment: Since he mentions a browser window and being new to JavaScript, Occam's razor would suggest client JS...

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can display your document in `<div id="target"></div>` like this:

```
$('#target').load('/database/document-id');
```

To actually receive the document as a JavaScript object and manipulate it:

```
$.get('/database/document-id',{},function(doc) {
  // Do something with 'doc' here: 
  alert(doc._id);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check out the Javascript examples here: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/tree/master/share/server